# How to unlist dataframes within a list into several dataframes itself?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to bring my dataframes within a list out of the list to have several dataframes at the end. Additionally I would like to give them automatically the name which they had before I read them into a list, with adding an ending name ".done" for example and write.table() back into my folder where the original data comes from for every dataframe.done in my environment.
Here my example data

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(94756)
mat1 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11),50, replace = TRUE),ncol = 5) 
mat1 <- as_tibble(mat1)

mat2 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11),50, replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
mat2 <- as_tibble(mat2)

mat3 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11), 50,replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
mat3 <- as_tibble(mat3)

data <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the list based on names (and it will be a named list this way)

```
data = mget(ls(pattern = "mat\\d+")) ## use a regex pattern to create a named list
data = lapply(data, as_tibble) ## convert the matrices to tibbles
names(data) = paste0(names(data), ".done") ## modify the names
list2env(data, envir = .GlobalEnv) ## put them back in global environment
```

Read more advice on this at [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207)

Comment: Ok the names of the dataframes are more difficult, like "Data_Date01.31.22Time11.43.46.xlsx". And I let them read in automatically via folder name. So they're not really named in R itself. How does the first line look like then and how can I bring the names in R as well if necessary?

Comment: Depends how specific you need to be. `pattern = "^Data_Date.*"` will work if you want all objects that start with the pattern "Data_Date". `pattern = "xlsx$"` will give everything ending in "xlsx". Or `pattern = "^Data_Date.*xlsx$` is more specific, requiring that they start with "Data_Date" and end in "xlsx". You can find a intro to regex to understand what's going on there and learn about the possibilities.

Comment: If I write your pattern in comment and ```names(data) <- paste0(files, ".done")``` it works. files it's the files I read in from a folder.